# Calculate average and running total in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this following table #temp1 with the following column names

| Month | RecordTotalByMonth | Type | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | New | Wellness |
| 2 | 20 | New | Wellness |
| 3 | 30 | New | Wellness |
| 4 | 30 | New | Wellness |
| 1 | 15 | Average Claim Size | Wellness |
| 2 | 15 | Average Claim Size | Wellness |
| 3 | 30 | Average Claim Size | Wellness |
| 4 | 10 | Average Claim Size | Wellness |
| 1 | 10 | New | Accident |
| 2 | 20 | New | Accident |
| 3 | 30 | New | Accident |
| 4 | 30 | New | Accident |
| 1 | 15 | Average Claim Size | Accident |
| 2 | 15 | Average Claim Size | Accident |
| 3 | 30 | Average Claim Size | Accident |
| 4 | 10 | Average Claim Size | Accident |

Now I would like to calculate AVG and running total in the **new** column "Total or Average".
Calculate **running total** by months where Product = 'Wellness' or Product = 'Accident' and Type = 'New'.
But calculate **Average** where Product = 'Wellness' or Product = 'Accident' and Type = 'Average claim size'.
End result should look like this

| Month | Record Total By Month | Type | Product | Total or Average |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | New | Wellness | 10 |
| 2 | 20 | New | Wellness | 30 |
| 3 | 30 | New | Wellness | 60 |
| 4 | 30 | New | Wellness | 90 |
| 1 | 15 | Average Claim Size | Wellness | 20 |
| 2 | 15 | Average Claim Size | Wellness | 20 |
| 3 | 30 | Average Claim Size | Wellness | 20 |
| 4 | 20 | Average Claim Size | Wellness | 20 |
| 1 | 10 | New | Accident | 10 |
| 2 | 20 | New | Accident | 30 |
| 3 | 30 | New | Accident | 60 |
| 4 | 30 | New | Accident | 90 |
| 1 | 10 | Average Claim Size | Accident | 15 |
| 2 | 10 | Average Claim Size | Accident | 15 |
| 3 | 30 | Average Claim Size | Accident | 15 |
| 4 | 10 | Average Claim Size | Accident | 15 |

My attempt

```
select  Monthly                                     
        , RecordTotalByMonth
        , Product
        , Type
        , sum(RecordTotalByMonth) over (partition by Product) as [Total or Average]
INTO New_table
from #temp1 
where Type = 'New'


Insert into New_table               
SELECT    Monthly                                       
        , RecordTotalByMonth
        , Product
        , Type
        , avg(RecordTotalByMonth) over (partition by Type) as [Total or Average]
from #temp1
where Type = 'Average Claim Size'
```

Comment: Can you share yout try?

Comment: @budhi my attempt is wrong, total comes upto 180 because it's only looking at Type = 'New'

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[Multiple Running Totals with Group By](/q/10368308/90527)", "[Calculate a Running Total in SQL Server](/q/860966/90527)", "[Running Total (pre 2012) for more than 1 group](/q/21029973/90527)", "[Average of grouped rows in Sql Server](/q/3100921/90527)", …

Comment: As per the [site guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) in the [help], please [search](/help/searching) before posting. See also "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/90527)"

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
SELECT month,
       recordtotalbymonth,
       type,
       product,
       CASE
         WHEN ( ( product = 'Wellness'
                   OR product = 'Accident' )
                AND type = 'New' ) THEN Sum(recordtotalbymonth)
                                          OVER (
                                            partition BY product, type
                                            ORDER BY month)
         WHEN ( ( product = 'Wellness'
                   OR product = 'Accident' )
                AND type = 'Average claim size' ) THEN Avg(recordtotalbymonth)
         OVER (
           partition BY product, type
           ORDER BY month)
       END AS "Total or Average"
FROM   t1;
```